# Javascript override problem class xml

Tags: javascript, xml, class, overriding, image-gallery

Probably this is a basic stuff, but better learn now then later.

**What i'm doing :** 
I 'm implementing a gallery that is getting a xml, and then build me using some javascript code. the problem i tried to call twice gallery.init like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    galleryXML.init({
        xmlPath : "data/gallery.xml",
        imgPath : "images",
        perView : 4,
        id: "#gallery1"
    });
    galleryXML.init({
        xmlPath : "data/gallery.xml",
        imgPath : "images",
        perView : 4,
        id: "#gallery"
    }); 
})
```

I expected to have one in #gallery1 other in #gallery. Can someone tell me what the problem?

The rest of the code is [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/dIPssYFK/source.html) only need to download, unrar and execute the index.html (Working just in firefox, not sure why too)

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

This is a minimal example for now, not sure if represent well the problem.

[http://jsfiddle.net/*PSYCKIC*/rpNab/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/_PSYCKIC_/rpNab/2/) -> **UPDATED**

Comment: For situations like this, where you really need to see the code involved, you'll get a quicker answer if you create a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ . This way you're not asking someone to download+run files locally.  Also, if it's a jQuery plugin, a link to the api reference would help.

Comment: Yep thanks, but it have several resources :/ photos ...was dificulty..try to minimize

Comment: If you want help, you need to provide much simpler access to the relevant code.   In this case, we need to see what the galleryXML.init() function does and any other relevant functions that it may call or use.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PSYCKIC/rpNab/2/ -> UPDATED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem can be that you are using the same variable `_P` for (what you expect to be) 2 different instances of the galleryXML.

The `_P` variable is created and initialized when the javascript code is parsed, because of the `()` after the `var galleryXML = function() {...}`.

So I guess your problem is going to be solved if you just put the variable inside the init of galleryXML. You can see the code here: **[jsfiddle.net/rpNab/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/rpNab/3/)** (notice that now each `li` is inside each gallery, instead of both `li` in the last gallery)

**EDIT:** And I realize that now with my modification the galleryXML module seems ugly (because it only has one method and no variables), so I made a minor refactoring in order to have more methods inside that class, but the methods now must receive the parameter because the class itself continue to be "static", but the parameters can make it act for different contexts. Hope it helps: **[jsfiddle.net/rpNab/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/rpNab/4/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot , it solve my problem..i thought i had to do "deep copy" or something

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works just fine in your jsFiddle example. The only reason why you weren't seeing the `li` show up is because you forgot to add styling for that particular `li`. Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZj7p/2/) with your code remaining the same and proper li styling.

Comment: Thanks , seems the problem is whit the xml ajax code... I updated the jsfiddle. Sorry http://jsfiddle.net/_PSYCKIC_/rpNab/2/